# How can i use FilterExpression over Nested Attributes in DynamoDB (Python)?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto, boto3

Here is my json model:

```
item=item={"Company":"ABCD",
               "Industry":"Invest.Services",
               "Sector":"Financial",
               "Financial_Results":
                             [{"Date":"2007-03-31","Frequency":"Annual","REV1":"20","REV3":"33"},
                              {"Date":"2008-03-31","Frequency":"Annual","REV1":"20","REV3":"34.43"},
                              {"Date":"2012-03-31","Frequency":"Annual","REV1":"30","REV3":Decimal("230")},
                              {"Date":"2013-03-31","Frequency":"Quarterly","REV1":Decimal("30"),"REV3":"3.32"},
                              {"Date":"2013-06-31","Frequency":"Quarterly","REV1":Decimal("20"),"REV3":"-0.343"},
                              {"Date":"2013-09-31","Frequency":"Quarterly","REV1":"20.50","REV3":"-0.543"}]
             }
    table.put_item(Item=item)

item=item={"Company":"EFGH",
               "Industry":"Mining",
               "Sector":"Metals",
               "Financial_Results":
                             [{"Date":"2007-03-31","Frequency":"Annual","REV1":"20","REV3":"33"},
                              {"Date":"2008-03-31","Frequency":"Annual","REV1":"20","REV3":"34.43"},
                              {"Date":"2012-03-31","Frequency":"Annual","REV1":"30","REV3":Decimal("230")},
                              {"Date":"2013-03-31","Frequency":"Quarterly","REV1":Decimal("30"),"REV3":"3.32"},
                              {"Date":"2013-06-31","Frequency":"Quarterly","REV1":Decimal("20"),"REV3":"-0.343"},
                              {"Date":"2014-03-31","Frequency":"Annual","REV1":"20.50","REV3":"-0.543"}]
             }
    table.put_item(Item=item)
```

Company - Partition key (Hash Key).

No Range Key(Sort key).

**My Requirements are:**

- How can i filter the 'Date' attribute equivalent or more than '2013-03-31' and 'REV1' attribute with less than zero items only.

Note:
I have referred the following link
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.Attributes.html#DocumentPaths

I still dont get any conclusions.Kindly help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [mcve] example and also check [ask] so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: Simply it is not possible as it is a list of objects.

Comment: @notionquest thank you for your valuable reply. But is there any alternate way that i could get the same functionality as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atlast i found an answer after made R&D for a whole day. **As per AWS DynamoDB documentation and other serious researches, I conclude that my json model preparation ( At the Top ) is currently not supported**.As per my requirement, I need to flatten my data instead of document basis.Thanks for every contributors though.